# How to launch a file in UWP?

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I want to launch the xml file from local state folder of my appx. I am unable to launch file using `var file= ApplicationData.current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync();
Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file)`.Is there any way to launch the file in UWP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that there is some issue with the default option you open the xml file with. And I have tried to launch a xml file with following code. And it works pretty well. The default application that I used to open xml file was Microsoft Edge.

```
string xmlFile = @"TextFile.xml";

var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(xmlFile);

if (file != null)
 {

     var success = await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);

     if (success)
     {
         // File launched
     }
     else
     {
         // File launch failed
     }
 }
 else
 {
     // Could not find file
 }
```

Please try to change the default apps to load xml file normally.